# Pinterest Send Pin View How to create the same one?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, user-interface, pinterest

Does anyone know how to create the following View Controller which is using in Pinterest App to send a pins or pick a board function?[image]

On the background view we can see the parent view that display pins for Design Category. It seems to me that it is just a custom `UITableViewController` presented as ChildView with transparent first cell and background of `UITableViewController`, but how to set deep of background view? Is it just a screenshot of View which is in the smaller size and set as a background of `UITableView` ? Can I use special method to manage deep of `UIViewController`?

EDITED 
[image]

Thanks for help

Comment: It's most likely just a snapshot, manipulated with a blur and transform. So not really the parent view but just an illusion of it to provide that depth effect. That's how these sorts of things are usually done.

Comment: Thank you Dima for your comment, but how to manipulate snapshot. In this case when User is scrolling down UITableViewController, the background snapshot became more Visible and then very quickly became current view controller. How to do that? I have posted other Photo